# Redirect URL after contribution

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page, redirect

Profiles let you direct to some odd page after submission - why do contribution pages go nowhere (or maybe they do?)?
Cheers

Comment: There is this: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviContribute+Redirect+to+External+Thank+You+Page; but it's terrible for non-coders...

Answer (score 3):

You might find this Fuzion extension does what you need. [Front End Page options](https://civicrm.org/extensions/front-end-page-options) adds the ability to choose an alternate thank you page instead of standard CiviCRM thank you page

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet - but from the reading: should work! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@petednz - fuzion's answer will work - but it's eluded me. So here's a bit of a work-around:
In the Contribution configuration mode go to "Receipt" and add in the Thank you message/footer a link that can be formatted to look like a button ->

```
<p><a class="johnbutton" href="http://xyz/members-home/">Go to your membership page</a></p>
```

Why not use the `<button>` or `<input>` tags? Somehow they trigger an input that collides with the CiviCRM form...

I.e. its not a real redirect, but gives the user the option to trigger one.